# Unable to Activate appService, Program is blocked by group policy

Tags: uwp

I have a UWP appService (e.g. `<uap:Extension Category="windows.appService"`) that was working fine that no longer deploys to Windows after upgrading to 15063.

When I start without debugging from Visual Studio I get "Unable to activate Windows Store app ... The activation request failed with error 'This program is blocked by group policy ..."

I've tried manually uninstalling the app, rebooting, and clearing out my bin and obj directories.  I'm not connected to AD, and I've tried and setting everything to Enabled (from Undefined) in

```
Local Computer Policy -> Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> App Package Deployment"
```

What am I doing wrong?  Has something changed in 15063 for appServices?

Comment: Have you tried [App services sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AppServices)? Does this sample have the same issue?

Comment: Yes, the App service sample had the same problem.  The problem is I'm an idiot.  I completely forgot you can't debug app services, you have to "Deploy" them.  In my defense the error message threw me off.  Not sure if I should delete the question or if it might help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't debug app services out of the box.  The error message is a red herring. 
 Instead right click and select "Deploy".

Or if you want breakpoints to hit Project Properties -> Debug -> Start action = Do not launch, but debug your code when it starts.